# Can't see the rep at the question but in the stats on user page

Tags: support

I see that in [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1949546/44852) I have zero upvotes. However, the notification bar said that I got two and when I check out the stats on my user page I can see that I got +something too. IN fact I see +8, assumingly being +2 for accepting the answer but also twice +3 for an upvote.

What am I missing? And why only +3? At StackOver we get +5...

Comment: You have one upvote (+5) and one downvote (-2) for a total of (+3)

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/44852/konrad-viltersten?tab=reputation

Comment: @Thomas I do? If you follow the link provided it says +6 and +5/-2. Perhaps I'm not understanding the +6-part...

Comment: @Thomas Nevermind. It's me being stupid. I forgot one could gain rep for editions when under 1000-level. I'm usually on StackOver and there I've got 9k, so the grace period of <1k is long forgotten. My bad.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.